# How to create an auto updatable named range with all my sheet names?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to create a VLOOKUP to search strings in all my worksheets. I found the code to do that however I need to have a named range with all my sheet names on it. However the file I am creating will have new sheets added to it every week and because of this I need to have that named range with all my sheet names automatically update when I add, rename or remove sheets.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim LookUpRange As Range, FoundRange As Range
    Dim VLookupCol As Long

    SearchString = "Bingo"

    'Number of columns  for VLookup
    VLookupCol = 3

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Search in each worksheet used range

        With ws
            Set LookUpRange = .UsedRange
            'Found range
            Set FoundRange = LookUpRange.Find(what:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox .Cells(FoundRange.Row, FoundRange.Column + VLookupCol).Value
            End If
        End With

    Next ws

End Sub
```